# VirtualBox: Need example of MSDOS with IP stack to share folders with host machine

Tags: virtualbox, ip, ms-dos

Does anyone have an example of the config.sys and autoexec.bat to setup an IP stack on a MSDOS virtual machine so I can share information between the virtual machine and the host? A downloadle VHD would be even more welcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think a virtual drive (floppy or HDD) plus some scripts to manage it would offer a much better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I have a DOS machine with LANMan for networking. It worked with XP. DOS is 16-bit so it won't network with much past XP.

It will network with a 32-bit machine and 32-bit network stuff.

It won't network with a 64-bit machine at all.

**Note:** I have (recently) saved files from DOS onto my USB Floppy drive and recovered then files in my Windows 11 Host. That is a workaround that I have used successfully.

You need something like this:

Config.sys

```
DOS=HIGH,UMB
DEVICE=C:\DOS\HIMEM.SYS
DEVICE=C:\LANMAN.DOS\DRIVERS\DOSUTILS\EMM386.EXE NoEMS
rem DEVICE=C:\NET\EMM386.EXE NoEMS
rem DEVICE=C:\DOS\EMM386.EXE x=a000-f7ff NoEMS
DEVICE=C:\DOS\ANSI.SYS
DEVICE=C:\DOS\SETVER.EXE
rem DEVICE=C:\DOS\POWER.EXE
LASTDRIVE=Z
BUFFERS=30,0
FILES=50
rem SHELL=C:\DOS\COMMAND.COM C:\DOS /P /E:2048
STACKS=9,256
DEVICEHIGH=C:\CDROM\IBMIDECD.SYS /D:IBMCD100
DEVICEHIGH=C:\NET\IFSHLP.SYS
```

Autoexec.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
LH c:\cdrom\mscdex /d:ibmcd100 /m:10
PROMPT $p$g
PATH=C:\;C:\DOS;C:\BATCH;C:\UTIL;C:\NORTON;C:\EDIT
SET TEMP=C:\TEMP
SET COMSPEC=C:\DOS\COMMAND.COM
C:\DOS\MOUSE.COM
C:\Util\Dosedit
C:\Dosidle\Dosidle
rem C:\DOS\DOSSHELL.EXE
SET PATH=C:\NET;%PATH%
C:\NET\net initialize
C:\NET\netbind.com
C:\NET\umb.com
C:\NET\tcptsr.exe
C:\NET\tinyrfc.exe
C:\NET\nmtsr.exe
C:\NET\emsbfr.exe
C:\NET\net start
```

Comment: I very much doubt this is about the system architecture. The network abstracts that away. It’s just that modern operating systems no longer support these tremendously insecure protocols or they’re deactivated by default.

Comment: I agree with with you.  XP is insecure as well and the above will network DOS with XP but not past that.  Not, for example, with a Windows 7 64-bit host and newer SMB drivers,

Answer (score 0):

I found a freewaretool `ansicon` that should solve the ansi problem. I am now installing a virtual W10 22H2 32 bit machine and will go on from there. I will not have share issues and I can redirect LPT1: to an IP device (Therefore I needed the TCPIP stack in Windows 10). Thanks for the input.

Comment: The configs I gave you should work for a 32-bit host . Try them.  Modern day SMB may stop you. If so, what I gave you is pretty much all there is.